# use du to exclude mounted volumes but check root volume only

Tags: centos, centos-7, du

I am trying to check my disk usage, because my root volume is full. I'm on Centos 7.5.

I thought that giving du the -x flag gets it to ignore mounted volumes.

But when I check my disk usage on this centos box I get this output:

```
[root@bc1 /]# du -skx * | sort -nr | head -10
du: cannot access ‘proc/24813/task/24813/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24813/task/24813/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24813/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24813/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
207749412       data
61255660        home
1114652 usr
177732  var
138592  boot
124312  root
52112   run
34276   etc
52      tmp
0       sys
```

But the /data partition is mounted from another volume. And I want to exclude it.

```
[root@bc1 /]# df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda        246G  199G   36G  85% /data
```

Why is the -x flag to du not excluding this volume? And how do I get du to show me only the root volume?

Comment: Why not just use `df` to see which partitions are full/empty?

Comment: I'm using du because I want to find the things I can delete so clear up some space. I'm not just trying to find out how much space is used. What's the best way I can find the things I can delete to clear up space?

Comment: If you've got a GUI I'd try `baobab` too/instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in `/` and use the asterisk in `du -skx *` you're specifically asking du to look in data.

`echo *` should clarify what the asterisk is doing.

Try `du -skx /` instead.

Comment: Downside to this is that you don't see how much data is in each folder. `du -shx *` gives something like `140G    /`, when you'd really like a breakdown by folder. I haven't found a good solution for this besides using `--exclude` on the top level mounts.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to check the local directory space in "/" filesystem.
cd /

```
for d in `ls /` ; do cat /proc/mounts | awk '{print $2}' > ./dummy_file ; if grep -q $d ./dummy_file; then echo " $d is in seperate mount " ; else du -sh $d ; fi ; done
```

Comment: An explanation will be welcome.

Comment: Try this site
https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=for+d+in+%60ls+%2F%60+%3B+do+cat+%2Fproc%2Fmounts+%7C+awk+%27%7Bprint+%242%7D%27+%3E+.%2Fdummy_file+%3B+if+grep+-q+%24d+.%2Fdummy_file%3B+then+echo+%22+%24d+is+in+seperate+mount+%22+%3B+else+du+-sh+%24d+%3B+fi+%3B+done